# Using two single-column indexes in where and orderby clause

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, query-optimization, where-clause

I have googled a lot and couldn't find a clear answer to my question

assume we have this query

```
SELECT * WHERE user_id = x ORDER BY date_created
```

If we have a single column index on user_id and another one on date_created, does the optimizer use both indexes? or just user_id index?

Comment: Run an explain and see.

Comment: thanks alot... so you say that it can't use both of the indexes. right?

Comment: MySQL will use one index at a time for a particular table, you can use a composite index i.e. combination of both `(user_id, date_created)`

Comment: @RickJames Please remove the comments, and also the FALSE comment on [your website](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll) about Firefox....  

Comment: @Luuk - spurious comments deleted; antiquated line in blog removed.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE user_id = 123 
ORDER BY date_created
```

If you have two distinct indexes, then MySQL might use the index on `user_id` to apply the `where` predicate (if it believes that it will speed up the query, depending on the cardinality of your data, and other factor). It will not use the index on `date_created`, because it has no way to relate the intermediate resultset that satisfy the `where` predicate to that index.

For this query, you want a *compound index* on `(user_id, date_created)`. The database uses the first key in the index to filter the dataset: in the index B-tree, matching rows are already sorted by date, so the `order by` operation becoms a no-op.

I notice that you are using `select *`; this is not a good practice in general, and not good for performance. If there are other columns in the table than the user and date, this forces to database to look up at the table to bring the corresponding rows *after* filtering and ordering through the index, which can be more expensive than not using the index at all. If you just need a few columns, then enumerate them:

```
SELECT date_created, first_name, last_name 
FROM mytable
WHERE user_id = 123 
ORDER BY date_created
```

And have an index on `(user_id, date_created, first_name, last_name)`. That's a *covering* index: the database can execute the *whole* query using on the index, without looking up the table itself.

Comment: . . That part of the documentation probably isn't relevant when the query is being filtered.  It is trying to avoid a situation called *thrashing* where a table doesn't fit into memory and is being read out of order.  The documentation should be clear on that point.  And, it is not really about the `select *` it is about having *any* column other than the keys in the index.  Gosh, that part of the documentation is really misleading.

Comment: In general, GMB's answer is good.  But, as Gordon points out, he went off into potentially irrelevant directions.  Some clarifications:  The columns must be checked, hence `*` is not much difference in effort than a list of columns.  What _does_ matter is if there is an unneeded `TEXT` or `BLOB` column that is "off-record".  This is likely to take extra disk reads to do `SELECT *` instead of avoiding that column(s).

Comment: and the "off-record" fetches can lead to 'thrashing'.  I see a "good" index as one that handles `WHERE`, `GROUP BY`, and `ORDER BY and LIMIT`; a "better" index is one that does that and is "covering".  But, often, "covering" is not possible (because of `TEXT`) or not practical ('too many' columns).

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I removed that doc quote from my answer, since it is indeed misleading (to me as well!).

Comment: @RickJames: I meant to introduce the *covering* concept with that `select *` discussion. I edited my answer a little to (hopefully) make it a bit clearer.